# correctly parsing a CSV file from an FTP server with app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, csv, ftp, ftplib

I'm trying to read a CSV file from an FTP server and parse it on app engine.
I can access the file and read it to `StringIO` but when I try to loop over the files lines it just loops over every character instead of lines. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here:

```
ftp = FTP('ftp.mydomain.com', 'username', 'pwd')
ftp.set_pasv(True)
r = StringIO()
ftp.retrbinary('RETR test.csv', r.write)

csvfile = csv.reader(r.getvalue(), delimiter=',')

for line in csvfile: 
    print line
```

this ends up in something like this:

```
['O']
['R']
['D']
['E']
['R']
['N']
['O']
['', '']
['O']
['R']
['D']
['E']
['R']
['D']
['A']
['T']
['E']
['', '']
['I']
['N']
['V']
['O']
['I']
['C']
['E']
['N']
['O']
['', '']
...
```

What is the correct way to do this and correctly parse the file from FTP so the `csv` module can read it correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Split the long string on newlines; `csv.reader()` expects an *iterable*, where each iteration a line is yielded. You are giving it a string, iteration is over individual characters then:

```
csvfile = csv.reader(r.getvalue().splitlines(), delimiter=',')
```

You don't show how `StringIO()` was imported. If it is the *python version* (`from StringIO import StringIO`) you can simply seek back to the start and pass that in *directly*:

```
r.seek(0)
csvfile = csv.reader(r, delimiter=',')
```

Answer (score 2):

For Python 3.x and csv.DictReader:

```
bio = io.BytesIO()
resp = ftp.retrbinary("RETR " + filename, bio.write)
bio.seek(0)
csv_data = csv.DictReader(io.TextIOWrapper(bio, newline=None), delimiter=',')
for row in data:
    ...
```

It took me a while to find this solution so I'm posting it. The answers I found did not address the problem to preserve the data in a way that would make `DictReader` happy.

If you don't care about `DictReader` the following might work out:

```
sio = io.StringIO()
resp = ftp.retrlines("RETR " + filename, sio.write)
sio.seek(0)
```

Not that you need the `retrlines` because the Python3 `StringIO` does not accept binary.